Response of Picker API return wrong picture
response pictureI use Picker API for google photos sharing, everything works but the response of API return is not picked photos. All responded photos show up the same as attachments. I tried my application in testing and publishing but got the same result.
This is response with baseUrl is not my image
[body] => { "mediaItems": [ { "id": "AF6xeaxx_dR6tT-QYkc8NHPE4SkMsc3knzFcDLm8gclQmRgQestdFmVzIxQipz2uge57-ZehEJQWR0JNLdMucrku1j6JppjemA", "createTime": "2024-12-07T02:29:13.171Z", "type": "PHOTO", "mediaFile": { "baseUrl": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/ppa/AFh6g8F_tlvviaxg4EGD1KNlmJkscWL-UZ59N512PDgQLk3VFR9qeb7wPNLruFgRtfZKMUU8b8DJHA", "mimeType": "image/jpeg", "mediaFileMetadata": { "width": 1536, "height": 2048 }, "filename": "8e94fa2c-2271-44a5-a515-cd1d5b1b04bb.jpeg" } }, 

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
